# ASP.Net Web API and ASP.Net Identity check session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-identity

I have an single page application that has to send some queries (well, http get or post, whatever) to the server and get to know whether the session is still alive or not.

More specifically, if the user is still logged in or not.

I've set SlidingExpiration to true so the framework will re-issue a new cookie everytime it processes a request which is halfway through the expiration window and also ExpireTimeSpan to 2 minutes.

I have an api controller that looks like that:

```
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/session")]
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]

public class SessionController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.Route]
    public int GetSessionState()
    {
        return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Even after 10 minutes, this one returns always 1.

My guess would be that the SessionState attribute is not supposed to be working here.

So after quite some research I am actually not sure anymore about the source of the problem. I am the only one doing that sort of thing?

Does anyone knows how to fix that thing and meet the requirements?

Thanks,

Comment: Could it be that by having your app execute the call to this controller, the session is now refreshed? I suppose that attribute is suppose to prevent that, but I'd think you could check if the expiration time has expired or been updated?

Comment: I tried to not send the call and after 2 minutes, if I refresh the page, I'm logged out. If I send the calls I never log out. Maybe the attribute is not meant to be used on a WebApi controller. But then I'd love to know which attribute/technique I should use to get it to work on WebApi

Comment: So I tried a solution from a friend that consist to remove the Cookie from the response. This is taking advantage from the SlidingExpiration and makes sure the browser does not get the updated cookie. However, debugging that solution, I get the strange result that HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies is empty. I really don't get how that thing is working now...

Comment: OK so apparently the OWIN uses his own cookie store here HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Response.Cookies... However, this still does not contain my session cookie...

Answer (score 1):

It occurs to me that the heart of your problem is that the server really can't answer if you should be logged it if it has to be logged in with a cookie to answer the question! In the past I have seen a javascript function given an expiration time that fires on a known interval and compares the current time to that and logs out if has passed. Really, that's all you are asking the server to do anyway, isn't it? I'd set it up so the server sets the parameters, but the client doesn't rely on the server to execute. Make sense?

Comment: Hello Philip, Thanks for the answer. The heart of my problem is that I use a Single Page Application. So if the user leaves the page open for too long, when he comes back and the session timed out, he might encounter issues as the navigation events are handled client side, only the API calls are getting to the server. So I did implement a successful solution that, for a specific call, removes the cookie from the response (with a filter attribute) but my problem here is that it seems Asp.Net Identity / OWIN is adding that cookie very late in the process and therefore I cannot kick it out.

Comment: Right. In a recent project the way we handled it was that after this client side timeout, the spa was redirected (client side) to the login page. Another variation is to have your api calls return proper codes that are handled in the error handler and understand the http code, most likely 401, and then redirect to the login page, or login state of your spa